# Magnific Popup closes when removing list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I have a Magnific Popup where I have a button that dynamically adds list items. In every list item there is a button that removes the list item. However when the list item is removed it also closes the popup. When I open the popup again the list item is gone. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sxfen

HTML:

```
<a href="#dialog" class="open-popup-link">Show popup</a>

<!-- Popup -->
<div id="dialog" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
<span><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="listitem_add" class="required">Add list item</a></span>
<section id="listitems"><ul></ul></section>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline'
});

$("#listitem_add").click(function () {
    $("#dialog #listitems ul").append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='listitem_delete'>Delete this list item</a></li>");

    $("#dialog #listitems .listitem_delete").off("click").click(function () {
        $(this).parent("li").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't have a great answer to why it is happening, but I was able to fix the issue by first hiding the element and then removing it. Here is the working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jhFgm. It might be due to the propagation of the event. You can learn more about event propagation here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventbubbling.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the click from traveling down the DOM tree

```
$("#dialog #listitems .listitem_delete").off("click").click( function (e) {  
    e.stopPropagation();        
    $(this).parent("li").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

@epascarello answer is correct. Some clarification about why this is happening: before the closing, popup checks if the clicked element is inside the popup, as you `remove()` it - it's outside - so popup closes.

Edit: forgot to mention that you may also add CSS class `mfp-prevent-close` to those list elements to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

HERE : [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Acvhy)

binding once:

```
 .....find('.listitem_delete').one('click', function (event) {  
 $(this).parent('li').remove();
 event.stopPropagation(); 
 event.preventDefault();
 });
```

and preventing defaults....

Have fun